# Thinkcentre automatically restart after turned off

Tags: 12.04

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 into my thinkcentre m83. The problem is everytime I shut down the system, after one second, it automatically restarts. Is there any one that can fix the problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo shutdown -h now` from terminal.  Does it work?

Comment: No, it does not work. I have tried many solutions. Some suggest to edit /etc/default/grub, but this cannot solve the issue on my machine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try this.  Go to BIOS Power menu, select Automatic Power On and Disable Wake on Lan.